# cordova maintain page status after back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, redirect

I've done an application that get data from a web service, those data generate `div`s on scroll, so if I scroll down I load more data and so on...
when I click on one of this `div` o get redirect by:

```
function redirect_click(clicked_id,soggetto,div_id){
        return function(){
         var fff=document.getElementById("d"+div_id);
         fff.style.backgroundColor=("#D6D6C2");
         fff.style.color=("white");
         sessionStorage.setItem("Soggetto", clicked_id);
         sessionStorage.setItem("Soggetto_nome", soggetto);
         window.location = "address.html";
        }
    }
```

So window.location drive me on address.html page...

All I want to achieve is when I come back from address.html to the previous page with back button (or another button that bring me back) I got all the data I've loaded from that moment (the data is alphabetically ordered so let's say I scroll down to G letter and then I click "GIGIO" when I come back I want to be on the letter G).

I searched "maintain page status after redirect" but I didn't find anything.

Also, previously I saved data with `session.storage` but I don't know if it's the right manner to do this.

Comment: best thing you can do is not redirect, use a single page application where you "navigate" to divs inside the app and not different .html files

Comment: infact i was thinking to this option...but for now i've got different pages...

Comment: but...when the user click back button i must intercept that event?

Comment: I think it's not necessary if you navigate to the divs with anchors

Comment: saving the html of the content of the page as a variable and reset the innerhtml when back solved...but i miss the javascript listener like this...